# increase value of variable in iteration of for loop robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to increase `${success_num}` test case variable in For Loop:
But it is always 0, even after I add 1 to it. It's like it's been reset after each iteration. How can I increase its value?

```
*** Test Cases ***
    ...
    ...
    Set Test Variable    ${success_num}    ${0}
    App For Port    ${actual_app}
    ...
    ...

*** Keywords ***
App For Port    [Arguments]    ${app}
    : FOR    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    ${PorF}    ${message}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    applicationcontrol.Launch application    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    Continue For Loop If    '${PorF}'=='FALSE'
    \    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check launching status    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    Continue For Loop If    '${status}'=='False'
    \    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='True'   Add Success
    \    Exit For Loop

Add Success
    ${success_num}    Set Variable    ${success_num+1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the keyword `Add Success` to:

```
Add Success
    ${temp}    Evaluate    ${success_num} + 1
    Set Test Variable    ${success_num}    ${temp}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to call a keyword to increase success_num:

```
App For Port    [Arguments]    ${app}
    : FOR    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    ${PorF}    ${message}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    applicationcontrol.Launch application    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    Continue For Loop If    '${PorF}'=='FALSE'
    \    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check launching status    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    Continue For Loop If    '${status}'=='False'
    \    ${success_num} =  Run Keyword If    ${status}    Set Variable  ${success_num}+1    ELSE    Set Variable    ${success_num}
    \    ${temp} =  Run Keyword If    ${status}    Evaluate  ${success_num}+1    ELSE    Evaluate    ${success_num}
    \    Set Test Variable  ${success_num}  ${temp}
    \    Exit For Loop
```

Comment: This is not working. It shows `INFO   ${success_num} = 0+1`, yet it's always 0

Comment: I changed your  code to this:  `Run Keyword If    ${status}    Set Test Variable    ${success_num}    ${success_num}+1    ELSE    Set Test Variable    ${success_num}    ${success_num}` and ran it. then it shows  `${success_num} = 0+1`  in the 1st iteration and  `${success_num} = 0+1+1`  in the 2nd iteration.  and when I finally do `${fail_num} = BuiltIn . Evaluate ${total_num} - ${success_num}`  it gives me 7.   this is ridiculous

Comment: @henry oh yes, I should have used "evaluate" instead of "Set Variable" (like  you show in the other answer). I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a Python function:

```
def Increment_Variable(p_num):
    return  int(p_num) + 1
```

and calling it as

```
${counter}=  Increment Variable  ${counter}
```